# Fitting a trapezoid with curve_fit

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit a trapezoid to a set of time series using the curve_fit library from scipy.optimize. The function that I'm using to generate a trapezoid is the following:

```
def trapezoid(x, a, b, c, tau1, tau2):
    y = np.zeros(len(x))
    c = -np.abs(c)
    a = np.abs(a)
    y[:int(tau1)] =  a*x[:int(tau1)] + b
    y[int(tau1):int(tau2)] =  a*tau1 + b 
    y[int(tau2):] = c*(x[int(tau2):]-tau2) + (a*tau1 + b)
    return y
```

Where a and c are the slopes, and tau1 and tau2 mark the beginning and the end of the flat phase.

And in order to fit I just use:

```
popt, pcov = curve_fit(trapezoid, xdata, ydata, method = 'lm')
```

For most of the cases it works just fine, such as in the following:
[image: Good fit]

However, I'm also getting some cases on which it just fails to fit the data, where it looks like it should be doing ok:

[image: Bad fit]

The problem with these cases is that it sets a tau2 (end of the flat phase) smaller than tau1 (beginning of it).

Could anyone suggest a way to solve this issue? Whether by imposing a constraint or in some other way?

Example array for which the fit does not work:

array([1.2 , 1.21, 1.2 , 1.19, 1.21, 1.22, 2.47, 2.53, 2.49, 2.39, 2.28,
       2.16, 2.07, 1.99, 1.91, 1.83, 1.74, 1.65, 1.57, 1.5 , 1.45, 1.41,
       1.38, 1.35, 1.33, 1.29, 1.24, 1.19, 1.14, 1.11, 1.07, 1.04, 1.  ,
       0.95, 0.91, 0.87, 0.84, 0.8 , 0.77, 0.74, 0.72, 0.7 , 0.68, 0.66,
       0.63, 0.61, 0.59, 0.57, 0.55, 0.52, 0.5 , 0.48, 0.45, 0.43, 0.41,
       0.39, 0.38, 0.37, 0.37, 0.36, 0.35, 0.34, 0.34, 0.33])

Which yields: tau1: 8.45, tau2:5.99

Comment: set tau2 to the maximum off tau1 and tau2 and you are done

Comment: It seems that the optimizer got stuck in a local minimum due to bad initial solution. You did not provide a *p0* argument to *curve_fit*, so your trapezoid parameters are all initialized to 1. You might want to find a way to properly initialize your parameters, otherwise you better use a global optimizer such as SciPy's *differential_evolution*.

Comment: @Glostas, the problem is that when it fails to fit due to this reason it assings a tau1 and tau2 that are simply wrong, imposing the assignment you mention does not solve the problem. The ideal case would be to be able to add a constraint imposing tau2>tau1, but apparently it is not possible using this library.

Comment: Instead of defining *tau2* as the index of the flat phase, it might be better to define it as its length with *tau1* still marking its beginning.

Comment: Thanks @Kefeng91 I'm looking into that

Comment: @Mr.T it should still find the best fit, whether it has one or not. It should be able to fit a triangle, simply by searching for the best combination of parameters, the fit won't be perfect, but it should do ok. The problem is that I don't know how to impose a tau2 > tau1

Comment: @Mr.T No it is not an assumption, just updated with an example

Comment: Still, a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would probably help your case.

Comment: Can you give us the data, that create the bad fit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find lmfit (http://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/) useful for this problem.  Lmfit provides a slightly higher level interface to curve fitting, still based on the `scipy`optimizers, but with some better abstractions and features.

In particular for your question, `lmfit` parameters are Python objects that can have bounds, be fixed, or be written as simple algebraic constraints in terms of other variables.  This can support imposing `tau2 > tau1`.
The idea is essentially to set `tau2=tau1+taudiff` and place a lower bound of 0 on `taudiff`.   While you could rewrite your function to do that in the code, with `lmfit` you don't have to do that and can put that logic in the Parameters instead.

Converting your script to use lmfit would give something like this:

```
from lmfit import Model

# use your same model function
def trapezoid(x, a, b, c, tau1, tau2):
    y = np.zeros(len(x))
    c = -np.abs(c)
    a = np.abs(a)
    y[:int(tau1)] =  a*x[:int(tau1)] + b
    y[int(tau1):int(tau2)] =  a*tau1 + b 
    y[int(tau2):] = c*(x[int(tau2):]-tau2) + (a*tau1 + b)
    return y

# turn model function into lmfit Model
tmod = Model(trapezoid)

# create Parameters for this model: they will be *named* according
# to the signature of the model function, and be used as keys in
# an ordered-directory-derived object.  Here you can also give
# initial values
params = tmod.make_params(a=1, b=2, c=0.5, tau1=5, tau2=-1)

# now you can set bounds or constraints.  

# 1st, add a new variable "taudiff"
params.add('taudiff', value=0.1, min=0, vary=True)

# constraint tau2 to be taudiff+tau1 -- this is no longer a "free variable:
params['tau2'].expr = "taudiff + tau1"

# now do fit to data:
result = tmod.fit(ydata, params, x=xdata)

# print report of fit
print(result.fit_report())

# get best fit params:
for parname, param in result.params:
    print(parname, param.value, param.stderr, param.expr)

# get best fit array for plotting
pylab.plot(xdata, ydata)
pylab.plot(xdata, result.best_fit)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I was looking for, works wonderfully.

Answer (score 1):

[image]Just setting t1,t2 to the minimum and maximum value does work

```
def trapezoid(x, a, b, c, tau1, tau2):
    y = np.zeros(len(x))
    c = -np.abs(c)
    a = np.abs(a)
    (tau1,tau2) = (min(tau1,tau2),max(tau1,tau2))

    y[:int(tau1)] =  a*x[:int(tau1)] + b
    y[int(tau1):int(tau2)] =  a*tau1 + b 
    y[int(tau2):] = c*(x[int(tau2):]-tau2) + (a*tau1 + b)



x_data = np.arange(len(A))
popt, pcov = curve_fit(trapezoid, x_data, A, method = 'lm')
print popt
fit = trapezoid(x_data,*popt)
```

leads to:

Comment: I tried, it still gives some erroneous results. Try this array([1.2 , 1.21, 1.2 , 1.19, 1.21, 1.22, 2.47, 2.53, 2.49, 2.39, 2.28,
       2.16, 2.07, 1.99, 1.91, 1.83, 1.74, 1.65, 1.57, 1.5 , 1.45, 1.41,
       1.38, 1.35, 1.33, 1.29, 1.24, 1.19, 1.14, 1.11, 1.07, 1.04, 1.  ,
       0.95, 0.91, 0.87, 0.84, 0.8 , 0.77, 0.74, 0.72, 0.7 , 0.68, 0.66,
       0.63, 0.61, 0.59, 0.57, 0.55, 0.52, 0.5 , 0.48, 0.45, 0.43, 0.41,
       0.39, 0.38, 0.37, 0.37, 0.36, 0.35, 0.34, 0.34, 0.33])

Comment: I the example you just showed, my solution gives, tau1=7.77 and tau2=7.85, which gives you a trapezoid. It just looks like a triangle